# A serious error occurred please contact the administrator

Tags: sitecore-client, speak, javascript

I am working on SPEAK UI in Sitecore.

I have created the button, Which is named as **Edit Meta** under `content/webedit/ribbons/webedit` in core database. This button will be shown in Experience Editor section when I click **Edit Meta** button. I need to show the Data in a popup window related to that particular Meta section. I gave the command name, script file path, Access Key in button layout properties.

When i click the button in Experience Editor it shows below error.

> A serious error occurred please contact the administrator

I un-commented the code which is related to SPEAK ui  in `sitecoreMvcExperienceEditor.config` also. I have added `Sitecore.Support.122942.dll` also.

I checked the log file and it shows `Could not instantiate speak request object`. Please suggest how to resolve this issue?

I followed below steps.

- I logged into `core` database using Sitecore Rocks.
- I have created the Item(Meta) using strip template under `Content/Applications/Webedit/Ribbons/Webedit/` in `core` database and given the Header Name and Id .
- Added strip layout for Meta Item in presentation details.
- Created the Item Under Meta by using Chunk template, given HeaderName and Added Chunk layout in presentation details.
- Created another item(EditMeta) under Meta chunk using Largebutton template & given the Header name also.
- Added the LargeButton rendering for MetaData in presentation details.
- I have edited the property details of Largebutton rendering. below I mentioned the property details of Largebutton rendering.
- [image]

My Js file.`

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor)


{

Sitecore.Commands.LaunchFieldEditor =
{
    canExecute: function (context) {
        return true;
    },
    execute: function (context) {


        context.currentContext.argument = context.button.viewModel.$el[0].accessKey;

        ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor("ExperienceEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl", function (response) {

            var DialogUrl = response.responseValue.value;
            var dialogFeatures = "dialogHeight: 680px;dialogWidth: 520px;";
            ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog(DialogUrl, '', dialogFeatures, null);
        }).execute(context);

    }
};
});
```

`

My class:

```
public class GenerateFieldEditorUrl : PipelineProcessorRequest<ItemContext>
{


public string GenerateUrl()

{
    var fieldList = CreateFieldDescriptors(RequestContext.Argument);
    var fieldeditorOption = new FieldEditorOptions(fieldList);
    //Save item when ok button is pressed
    fieldeditorOption.SaveItem = true;
    return fieldeditorOption.ToUrlString().ToString();
}
private List<FieldDescriptor> CreateFieldDescriptors(string fields)
{
    var fieldList = new List<FieldDescriptor>();
    var fieldString = new ListString(fields);
    foreach (string field in new ListString(fieldString))
        fieldList.Add(new FieldDescriptor(RequestContext.Item, field));
    return fieldList;
}
public override PipelineProcessorResponseValue ProcessRequest()
{
    return new PipelineProcessorResponseValue
    {
        Value = GenerateUrl()
    };
}
}
```

I added the reference in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.SpeakRequest.config`

```
<configuration>
<sitecore>
    <sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
        <request name="ExperienceEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl" type="Website.Modules.Components.ExperienceEditor.FieldEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl, Website.Modules" />
    </sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
</sitecore>
```

Could you please suggest, how to fix this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please open Sitecore logs, see what errors/exceptions happened around that time, and include those error messages as a part of your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is incomplete - without enough information to diagnose the issue - and possibly a bit off-topic. It looks like what the author really needs is some help getting through a tutorial/walkthrough, and I would expect that better help could probably be found by asking the question in Sitecore Community Slack

Comment: Putting the question on hold for now, awaiting clarification. Reopened 07/03/2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestArgs` class the method name to execute defaults to **Process**. Check the last line in below method.

```
public RequestArgs(string commandPath, NameValueCollection queryString, string data)
  {
   Assert.ArgumentNotNull(queryString, "queryString");
   this.QueryString = queryString;
   this.Data = data;
   string[] array = StringUtil.RemovePrefix('/', StringUtil.RemovePostfix('/', commandPath)).Split(new char[]
   {
    '/'
   });
   Assert.IsTrue(array.Any<string>(), "Missign request name");
   this.RequestName = array[0];
   this.MethodName = ((array.Length == 1) ? "Process" : array[1]);
  }
```

Either you have to create your request as `ExperienceEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl/ProcessRequest`

Or change the method below in GenerateFieldEditorUrl class to **Process** from **ProcessRequest**

```
public override PipelineProcessorResponseValue ProcessRequest()
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I work with Indra who created the question. Spent good 1 hour to reflect and found the answer

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering questions here, that you solved offline :-)  Just make sure you provide full question explanation, and full answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your log file.

- **There may be many scenarios:**

**Scenario 1 (I was facing this issue): Social Media is disabled in your** configuration file but related items do exist in CORE database.
ERROR: Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ExperienceEditor.Social.SocialCenter.GetMessagesCount error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ExperienceEditor.Social.SocialCenter.GetMessagesCount at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context) at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
Solution: Remove these two items from CORE DB:

**Solution:**
Remove these two items from CORE DB:
•   /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor/Social
•   /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Social

**Scenario 2:** URL Rewrite issue with SPEAK request

ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/optimization.activeitemtest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/optimization.activeitemtest

**Solution:** Well explained in given blog (However, this was not the problem I was facing).
https://codeandnuts.wordpress.com/2017/04/19/sitecore-experience-editor-issue-a-serious-error-occurred-please-contact-the-administrator/